# Why is SQL Count(*) returning 1 from an empty table?

Tags: mysql

So I am pretty new in MySQL.
I have a table, with no data in it (= empty table).
I am doing a SELECT COUNT(*) from table where table.xx AND table.YY.
Result is 1, but should be 0 ? (bc empty table).

*Note*: Primary code of table is table.id, so none of the one selected.

Thanks for the input !
Best,

```
$req_testLogIn = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE USERS_email='test' and USERS_pwd='test'");
$res_testLogIn = $req_testLogIn->execute();

if($res_testLogIn == 1){} //is true...
```

Comment: You're not checking the value that was returned by the query anywhere.

Comment: Hi @stickybit, thank you for the feedback. How should I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

[PDOStatement::execute docs:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.

And then [`TRUE == 1` is true](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: Thanks @Emmett, will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

@LNFullStack, you're on the right track its just that you are checking if the query was successful or not, but it was, so you get 1 which is true. So your code will always be true because your query was successful.

Whereas you should be checking if the query actually returned a row or not, in which case you should be checking for something like row count.

Example 1:

```
$req_testLogIn = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE USERS_email='test' and USERS_pwd='test'");
$res_testLogIn = $req_testLogIn->execute();

if($req_testLogIn->rowCount() ==1){...} //false because 0 rows found in table and false too if row is more than 1. Take note.
```

Example 2:

```
$req_testLogIn = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as totalUsers FROM users WHERE USERS_email='test' and USERS_pwd='test'");
$res_testLogIn = $req_testLogIn->execute();
$db_rows = $res_testLogInt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);       
if($db_rows->totalUsers ==1){...} //false because 0 rows found in table and false too if row is more than 1. Take note.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @pasignature, thanks for the input ! I miss-understood how this COUNT(*) was working.
I used "Example 1" ... but still I got a true whereas it should be false...with 
'''
echo $req_testLogIn->rowCount();
''''
output giving 1

Comment: What about example 2, try that.

Comment: Hello pasignature, Thanks. I used another way to verify the login without COUNT(*) but I’ll definitely keep exemple 2 in mind when need arise. Thank you again.